# SVG mouse cursor blurry on Retina display

Tags: retina, mouse-cursor

I'm using a custom SVG cursor on my webpage and it appears to be blurry on Retina screens. Is this a common issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into the same issue. My workaround involves using jQuery to follow the mouse position with an SVG div:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
$("#cursor").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
```

but this has one issue of its own which I haven't resolved - it does not follow the mouse position as you scroll like the css option does

jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/jhhbrook/ucuLefut/
CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/0chzmhrd/